# "Request token or token secret not set in server reply." when attempting to get the request token

Tags: android, oauth, twitter4j, signpost

I'm using the Twitter API with Signpost and Twitter4J on Android.

My code fails here:

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

// Here:
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK);
```

After a lengthy wait for the API, I get the exception:

> Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy.

I doubt this is Twitter's problem, so why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1-  Try changing https to http.                                        
2-  Callback should be line >x-latify-oauth-twitter://callback